# OnItemClick listener selects multiple rows in async filled list android

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have an list with is filled with contacts. I load the contacts in the list with an async class.

In the list class i have an setOnItemClickListener implemented. In this setOnItemClickListener i place the selected contact in an array so i can sent a  text to them. This is all working like a dream.

BUT there is a small problem. When selecting a contact in the list there are multiple contacts selected like this:

```
-normal contact-
-selected contact-
-normal contact-
-normal contact-
-normal contact-
-normal contact-
-selected contact-
```

i load the contacts with this code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<list_item_person> contacts) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(contacts);

        pd.cancel();




        PersonListAdapter adapter =  new PersonListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.list_item_person, contacts);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

this is the async class

and the onclick is like this:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            list_item_person o = (list_item_person) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
          SearchResults selected = new SearchResults("");
            int i = 0;
            for( SearchResults number:contact_selected){
                if(o.phoneNumber.equals(number.getPhoneNumber())){
                    i ++;
                    selected = number;
                }
            };
            if(i == 0) {
                contact_selected.add(new SearchResults(String.valueOf(o.phoneNumber)));
                arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                Log.e("e", String.valueOf(o.phoneNumber));
            }else{
                contact_selected.remove(selected);
                arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#162229"));
            }
```

What am i forgetting here?

Comment: You did not even tell what you consider to be a selected item. How does the user see that an item is selected?

Comment: `When selecting a contact in the list there are multiple contacts selected like this:`. Don't think so. Only after the user scrolls the list.

Comment: @greenapps an selected item is an item where the background color is red and the value of the number is placed in contact_selected

Comment: Please react on my scroll statement.

Comment: @greenapps befor and after scrolling this is the case

Comment: I hope you have a long list so the user has to scroll a lot. So at least three times the amount that can be seen on one screen. Now if the user selects item two. Then scrolls the list completely and comes back. Then what is selected?

Comment: @greenapps when i select a second item the same thing happends. When testing i also found out that 
A: the selection  is a random (between 8 and 17 rows apart)
B: it doesn't matter if the whole list has been seen or the place where there is an item selected(when in the middel selects top and bottom items)

Comment: I did not ask you to select a second item. Only one item. Item nr 2. I thought i described a simple scenario.  So why not test that?

Comment: @greenapps what i understand of your question i clicked on the first item. scrolled to the second selected item and tapped that. scrolled back up and saw the first on still selected

Comment: No that is not what i wanted you to do. Please reread and try again.

Comment: @greenapps  so i do that item 2 is selected and some random items in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are victim nr #### of the itmes/views which get recycled when the user scrolls the list. You can read a lot about this 'feature' on this site and many blogs.

Your code should remember (for instance in an boolean array or a  arraylist) the 'selected' state of every item. You could also add a boolean selected = false to your `list_item_person` too. In onClick() only change the value.

Then in getView() set always the color accordingg the selected state too.

To get this running first concentrate on keeping a selected state. So remove or comment out all you copying to arrays and so.